# How do I index foreign keys using Fluent NHibernate and SchemaUpdate.Execute()?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way in Fluent NHibernate to specify that a foreign key should be indexed?

MS Sql Server's default configuration does not index foreign keys.  I would like the schema generated by the NHibernate schema generation/update tools to index these keys. When I just use the `HasMany` or `HasManyToMany` methods, no such indexes are created. Is this even possible with raw XML mappings?

Comment: In case you didn't know, the reason foreign keys are not indexed by default is that can result in an overall decrease in application performance.  This feels like attempted optimization without profiling.

Comment: Michael - I'm not looking to do this for every FK in the schema - only where I know I need it. I am not at all critical of the fact that MS Sql Server does not index FK's by default. I do, however, need some means by which to index the FKs where it is neccessary. I would prefer, at least initially, that I can do this with Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the 'index' attribute on a column mapping element is what you are after. If you're on the latest version of FNH, you can set this for a one-to-many like so:

```
HasMany(x => x.Components)
       .KeyColumns.Add("ProductId", c => c.Index("someIndex");
```

The same API is not yet available for many-to-many's, but it is on its way.

Comment: Great - thx - that's what I was looking for. Looks like the version of FNH that I have (1.0 RTM) does not yet have that option - is this only available for a version that must be built from source?

Comment: You don't have to build from source. The download page has the latest builds. revision 595 should have this change. http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads

Comment: Ok - now I see the builds. Guess I should have scrolled down a few pixels instead of clicking on the first thing that said download that I saw :)